# how to send multiple pictures to the client, and how does the client display them?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I am running my server code which seems to be able to send pictures to the client, however it looks like that only one picture file is sent, which is totally black once is manually opened. Moreover, the client gets an error when trying to display the pictures received.

I have tried to convert bytes back to pictures and that is the part that gives me the error.

```
import cv2 #SERVER
import time
import socket
import glob
import os
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print("server started...")

path1 = (r"C:\Users\Desktop\opencvpics")
def readFileImages():
    st = os.path.join(path1, "*.png")
    print(st)
    return glob.glob(st)

list1 = readFileImages()
print(list1, "list1......")
print(type(list1))

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"connection from {addr} has been established !")
    c.send(bytes("welcome to the server".encode()))

    for pics in list1:
        f = open(pics, 'rb')
        l = f.read(1024)
        #while (l):
        c.send(l)
        print('Sent ', repr(l))
        #l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
        print(pics, "sdfasdfsadadfsafsas")
        print(type(f),type(l))

    print('Done sending')
    c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
```

```
import socket #CLIENT
from typing import Optional, Any
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import io
import pickle
host =  "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send('Hello server!'.encode())

with open('received_file.png', 'wb') as f:
    print('file is open')
    print('receiving data...')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print('data=%s', data)
    f.write(data)
    print('Successfully get the files')
    print('connection closed')
    print(type(data))
    print(len(data))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
    image.show()
s.close()
```

here is the error coming from the client, but please note that I had to shrink the code here in order to match the layout, so line 35 in this error message might correspond to another line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/client-server/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\client-server\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2818, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x07D02330>
```

Comment: Why `l = f.read(1024)` and not `l = f.read()`?

Comment: Also, you should write a new file on every receive on client side. Perhaps in a loop?

Comment: server first sends some welcome text but I don't see where client receive it - it seems you save this text as part of image. And you send only 1024 bytes of image but image can be much bigger.

Comment: maybe first try with only one image, and don't send any text. You may need some loop to send and receive more then 1024 bytes. Client doesn't know how big is file - so it doesn't know if it get all data and if has to wait for more bytes. It could be good to send first information with size of image. Some people uses module pickle to convert integer to text bytes which will have always the same size so client will know if it get full information about file size.

Comment: I already used this loop in the server side                                                                   ``` for pics in list1:
        f = open(pics, 'rb')```                                                                                                         how come it only iterates once instead of going through all the pictures ?